# Page exit notification unless submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onbeforeunload

Currently in my HTML I have it to where if the user tries to exit the page before filling out any of the form it will give an pop-up error asking if the user really wanted to exit the page.

But I am also getting that that error when I am having the user submit the page and have the page close after the page has been submitted.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
    var warning = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {  
  if (warning) {  
    return "If you leave this page uncompleted student will be marked as Abandon!";  
    }  
}

document.getElementById('StudentForm').submit(function() {
   window.onbeforeunload = null
    window.close;
});
```

Then the HTML form code:

```
<form name=StudentForm id="StudentForm">

    <div class="DDbox">
        <select name="Action" id="ActionDD" required onchange="showHide()">
        <option value="">Action:</option>
        <option value="complete">Complete</option>
        <option value="abandon">Abandon</option>
        <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="COMPLETEbox" id="COMPLETEbox" >
        <input class="hidden-items" type="text" name="RemNUM" id="REMtextBox" placeholder="Remedy Number" min="1" maxlength="10" style="display:none;"/><br>

        <select class="hidden-items" name="Reason" id="ReasonDD" style="display:none;">
        <option value="">Reason:</option>
        <option value="NoShow">No Show</option>
        <option value="Unfixable">Unfixable</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id=submitButton>
    </div>
</form>
```

The code right now works when exiting the page. The part I can not figure out is what to change to have to code figure out that the form is filled out and it is "OK" to close the page.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: "If you leave this page this student will be marked as abandonded. Are you sure?"

Answer (score 0):

By the way, showing a custom message in the dialog is [deprecated on Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480) and you **can't** prevent the person from leaving the page.

As for your validation, I suggest you take a look at [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Then on submit you can check if the form is valid.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var valid = $(this).valid();
    // Do stuff.
});
```